# score string created with label not erasing previous score while score changes dynamically-LibGdx

Tags: java, libgdx

In my game UI, I have a label on a box image to write score.

```
private void drawNoOfCoins() {
    Label.LabelStyle style = new Label.LabelStyle();
    style.font = game.font2;
    Label totalCoinLabel = new Label(coinScoreController.getTotalCoinString(), style);

    totalCoinLabel.setPosition(showcoinImage.getWidth() / 2,Constants.WORLD_HEIGHT - 2 * totalCoinLabel.getHeight());
    stage.addActor(totalCoinLabel);

    totalCoinLabel.setBounds( showcoinImage.getX(), showcoinImage.getY(),showcoinImage.getWidth(), showcoinImage.getHeight());
    totalCoinLabel.setAlignment( Align.center );    
}

private void ShowCoinScoreBox() {
    showcoinImage = new Image(showScoreTexture);
    showcoinImage.setPosition(Constants.WORLD_WIDTH / 42,Constants.WORLD_HEIGHT - (showcoinImage.getHeight() * 1.5f));
    stage.addActor(showcoinImage);
}
```

I am calling this method drawNoOfCoins() in render() and score is getting updated dynamically.

But every time the score changes dynamically,updated score is showing on top of the previous score.
Is this problem comes because of label or any other things?
How can I solve it?

Comment: You should *not* be adding the score to the stage every loop! Add the label to the stage once, during the initialization of the class and then keep a reference to the score label and update it as required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `ShowCoinScoreBox()` & `drawNoOfCoins()` at once from `ApplicationListener`'s `create()` or from `show()` method of `Screen` Interface for initialization. You're creating new `Actor` on render call and adding them to the stage.

Keep reference of `totalCoinLabel` globally instead of local.

```
private Label totalCoinLabel; 

private void drawNoOfCoins() {
    Label.LabelStyle style = new Label.LabelStyle();
    style.font = game.font2;
    totalCoinLabel = new Label(coinScoreController.getTotalCoinString(), style);

   ...    
}
```

Inside `render()` method update label text

```
totalCoinLabel.setText(coinScoreController.getTotalCoinString());
```